# Sort column values alphabtically

Tags: r, sorting

```
HospitalName                       | Rating
-----------------------------------|  ------
FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER         | 8.1
TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    | 8.5
DETAR HOSPITAL NAVARRO             | 8.7
CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER   | 8.7
```

Here is my sample table , you can see  In Hospital Name "DETAR HOSPITAL" and "Cypress FAIRBANKS " Having the same Rating .  I have sorted the table by the least rating to highest rating  but all I need is sort the Hospital Names alphabetically which have the same Rating, like "CYPRESS..." Should come first then "DETAR" though they having the same Rating but they need to be arranged alphabetically .

Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `order`

```
df1[order(df1$Rating, df1$HospitalName),]
#                      HospitalName Rating
#1       FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER    8.1
#2  TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    8.5
#4 CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER    8.7
#3           DETAR HOSPITAL NAVARRO    8.7
```

---

If we are using `dplyr`, `arrange` is the way to go

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(Rating, HospitalName)
```